# MySQL Connector/C++ crashes with g++8.1.0 and C++17

Tags: c++, gcc, mysql-connector

I just started programming in C++ using Visual Studio 2017 and connected to my database. Everything worked fine so far. Then I wanted to use a c++17 feature and realized I needed to upgrade my compiler.

After upgrading my compiler to g++8.1.0 using [this blog](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/12/08/raspberry-pi-raspbian-install-gcc-compile-cpp-17-programs/) with these commands (and a lot of trial and error):

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/sol_prog/raspberry-pi-gcc-binary.git
cd raspberry-pi-gcc-binary
tar xf gcc-8.1.0.tar.bz2
mv gcc-8.1.0 /usr/bin
cd ..
rm -r raspberry-pi-gcc-binary
rm /usr/bin/gcc
rm /usr/bin/g++
ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-8.1.0/bin/gcc-8.1.0 /usr/bin/gcc
ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-8.1.0/bin/g++-8.1.0 /usr/bin/g++

 # After getting the error "GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not found" I did the following:
rm /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6
 # I don't know if this (next line) was necessary
rm /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-8.1.0/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.25 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6
```

Now the program compiles, but when I excecute it, it crashes. When I switch to the old compiler (g++-4.9) it works again. Maybe the new compiler isn't properly installed. Instructions on how to install GCC-8 on Raspbian would be great.

This is basically the program:

```
#include<string>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<exception>

#include<mysql_driver.h> //OR #include<cppconn/driver.h>
#include<mysql_connection.h> //OR #include<cppconn/connection.h>

sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver* driver; //OR sql::Driver*
sql::Connection* conn;

int main(const int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  try {
        driver = sql::mysql::get_driver_instance(); //OR get_driver_instance();
        conn = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "MY_PW");
        conn->setSchema("MY_DB");
    } catch (std::exception &e) {
        //err("Failed to connect to the database.", e);
    }
}
```

And this is the error I get in Visual studio:

> Aborted (gdb) 1055-var-create - * "__size" (gdb)
>   1066-stack-select-frame 16 (gdb) 1067-var-create - * "argc" The thread
>   'LSTGA.out' (0x5cfa) has exited with code 0 (0x0). The program '' has
>   exited with code 0 (0x0).

And this is the error I get when running it directly via SSH:

> *** Error in `./LSTGA.out': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x7ec3c50c ***
>   Aborted

The call stack:

[image]

Additional information:

- Previous compiler: gcc-4.9 / g++-4.9 (still present)
- New compiler: gcc-8.1.0 / g++-8.1.0
- Previous LIBSTDC++: 6.0.22 (Removed)
- New LIBSTDC++: 6.0.25
- Remote machine: Raspberry Pi 2b
- Remote OS: Raspbian
- Local OS: Windows 10
- Visual studio Community 2017 15.8.8

Thanks in advance. *-Minding*

Comment: Just currious; if you have to upgrade your compiler, why would you go to gcc 8.1 and not straight to the latest 8.2.1 (at the time of writing) ?

Comment: @JesperJuhl very good question :D As I said, i'm new to C++ and don't know how get the newest version onto my raspberry pi, but if there is a package I could install (preferablly with apt-get) I would love to.

Comment: I'm not getting how Visual Studio factors into this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's just there for completeness, since it's starting the compiler and passing it arguments.

Comment: On a Raspberry Pi?! Or over some network connection? Either way, it's just a distraction - let's abstract that out of the question and just focus on the problem, which is that you can no longer get a working program built on your Raspberry Pi. The Windows 10 PC appears to be irrelevant.

Comment: ... unless the problem is with how you're doing remote debugging (the error message does say "gdb") but if so we really don't have enough information to diagnose that. At the very least you're going to have to better explain your setup...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm (building and) running the program through Visual Studio's Debug feature remotely on my raspberry pi in my home network. -- And now I got it working again using the old compiler, so I'm thinking that there is a problem with my new compiler installation.

Comment: How did you "get it working again using the old compiler?" What did you do? What did you change? Provide _detailed, exact reproduction steps_ in your question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think the old compiler worked the entire time and I was just confused. (Because I just copied the libstdc++.so.6.0.22 I removed earlier from another raspberry pi onto this one and it worked, but then I deleted it again and it still works.) So I'm pretty sure that it's really my new installation or a compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-bugs.html):

> Even a small change in the compiler version can cause problems. If you obtain error messages that you suspect are related to binary incompatibilities, build Connector/C++ from source, using the same compiler and linker that you use to build and link your application.

So the solution is to build the MySQL Connector/C++ from source as described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-installation-source.html).

I hope this helps.