# Building MySQL Connector/C++ from source with cmake fails (conflicts with a previous declaration)

Tags: c++, cmake, mysql-connector

I'm trying to compile the MySQL Connector/C++ 8.0.12 using gcc-8.1.0 and cmake 3.6.2, since the apt package seems to be compiled for gcc-4.9 and crashes when used with gcc-8.1.0 compiled programs (but works with gcc-4.9 compiled programs).

From the [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-bugs.html):

> Even a small change in the compiler version can cause problems. If you obtain error messages that you suspect are related to binary incompatibilities, build Connector/C++ from source, using the same compiler and linker that you use to build and link your application.

When I try to build the connector from source as described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-installation-source-cpp.html):

```
git clone https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-cpp.git
mkdir cppconn
cd cppconn

cmake /home/pi/mysql-connector-cpp
 # Everything looks fine except for:
Protobuf include path: /home/pi/mysql-connector-cpp/cdk/protobuf/protobuf-2.6.1/src
...
-- Performing Test HAVE_IS_SAME - Failed

cmake --build . --target install --config Debug
 # All lot of warings come up and then:
Scanning dependencies of target protobuf
...
[ 34%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/protobuf.dir/protobuf-2.6.1/src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc.o
In file included from /home/pi/mysql-connector-cpp/cdk/protobuf/protobuf-2.6.1/src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc:37:
/usr/bin/gcc-8.1.0/include/c++/8.1.0/math.h:65:12: error: ‘constexpr bool std::isinf(double)’ conflicts with a previous declaration
 using std::isinf;
            ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:374,
                 from /usr/bin/gcc-8.1.0/include/c++/8.1.0/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/os_defines.h:39,
                 from /usr/bin/gcc-8.1.0/include/c++/8.1.0/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/c++config.h:508,
                 from /usr/bin/gcc-8.1.0/include/c++/8.1.0/utility:68,
                 from /usr/bin/gcc-8.1.0/include/c++/8.1.0/algorithm:60,
                 from /home/pi/mysql-connector-cpp/cdk/protobuf/protobuf-2.6.1/src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc:35:
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/mathcalls.h:201:1: note: previous declaration ‘int isinf(double)’
 __MATHDECL_1 (int,isinf,, (_Mdouble_ __value)) __attribute__ ((__const__));
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /home/pi/mysql-connector-cpp/cdk/protobuf/protobuf-2.6.1/src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc:37:
/usr/bin/gcc-8.1.0/include/c++/8.1.0/math.h:66:12: error: ‘constexpr bool std::isnan(double)’ conflicts with a previous declaration
 using std::isnan;
            ^~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:374,
                 from /usr/bin/gcc-8.1.0/include/c++/8.1.0/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/os_defines.h:39,
                 from /usr/bin/gcc-8.1.0/include/c++/8.1.0/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/c++config.h:508,
                 from /usr/bin/gcc-8.1.0/include/c++/8.1.0/utility:68,
                 from /usr/bin/gcc-8.1.0/include/c++/8.1.0/algorithm:60,
                 from /home/pi/mysql-connector-cpp/cdk/protobuf/protobuf-2.6.1/src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc:35:
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/mathcalls.h:234:1: note: previous declaration ‘int isnan(double)’
 __MATHDECL_1 (int,isnan,, (_Mdouble_ __value)) __attribute__ ((__const__));
```

**The requirements stated by the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-cpp/8.0/building.html):**

- A C++ compiler that supports C++11. In case of gcc it must be at least version 4.8. These compilers have been tested: gcc 4.8.5, 5.4.0, 6.3.0, 6.3.1, 7.2.1, 7.3.0, 8.1.1, clang 9.0.0, MS Visual Studio 2015. **(present ~ 8.1.0)**
- CMake 2.8.12 or later. **(present - 3.6.2)**
- Boost 1.59 or later if the version of the C++ standard library used does not implement the UTF8 converter (codecvt_utf8). Boost is also required when building the legacy connector (see below). **(libstdc++.so.6.0.25 supports codecvt_utf8 to my knowledge)**
- OpenSSL version 1.0.x if connector is built with OpenSSL. Instead of OpenSSL the Connector/C++ can be build using WolfSSL 3.14.0 or newer. **(present - 1.0.1)**
- MySQL 8.0 client library if building the legacy connector (see below). **(not necessary)**

**Additional information:**

- using a Raspberry Pi 2b running Raspbian
- libstdc++ version is 6.0.25
- Protobuf version seems to be 2.6.1 (to be build)

Thanks in advance. *-Minding*

Comment: is gcc 8.1 compatible with your arm libraries?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I'm not sure, I am new to C++ and want to create a project with C++17 which requires a more recent compiler than the preinstalled gcc-4.9 and also want to be able to access my MySQL database.

Comment: It's not always possible. You need to compile with the latest compiler compatible with your arm libraries, and I fear that's not gcc 8 (or any C++17 compiler).

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Well it was tested with gcc-8.1.1 and I have gcc-8.0.13 but don't know where I can get any other gcc version for Raspberry Pis :( (I've updated my question)

Comment: Well, the connector may be compatible with 8.1, but not the arm libraries.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I don't understand which arm libraries, but the MySQL Connector package from apt for gcc-4.9 works on my Raspberry, but I can't use C++17 with gcc-4.9.

Comment: /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ That's the arm libraries, these have to be compatible with gcc 8. These are the cause of the errors, and these show that the arm libraries are not compatible with gcc 8.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Okay, thank you. There is still one thing I don't get though: Why can I compile and run my program with gcc-8.1.0 and it runs (when not using the MySQL Connector). Shouldn't it be incompatible as well?

Comment: It may depend on what headers are included :/ But perhaps someone will have a better answer.

Comment: Seems like gcc-8 should be compatible: "I've compiled GCC 8.1.0 for Raspberry Pi, enabled languages C and C++. The compilers should work with all current versions of Pi." - [Solarian Programmer](https://bitbucket.org/sol_prog/raspberry-pi-gcc-binary.git)

Comment: Have you used these libraries instead of the default ones at /usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/? Seems like there are headers in /usr/bin/gcc-8.1.0/include/c++/8.1.0/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ as well, the first ones coming fromt he system and too old and the new ones coming with gcc 8.

Comment: I've only replaced gcc and g++ itself in /usr/bin and libstdc++.so.6.0.25 in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf since I got an error without it. I didn't touch anything else because there are confusingly many files in there and I didn't want to mess up my system. (It also seemed to work fine) But if you could tell me how to properly "install" those, that would be great.

Comment: I followed [this](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/12/08/raspberry-pi-raspbian-install-gcc-compile-cpp-17-programs/) blog (by Solarian Programmer) to install gcc-8, but I did it a little differently than he. I described my steps [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53071286/mysql-connector-c-crashes-with-g8-1-0-and-c17).

Comment: You shouldn't use /usr/unclude/arm-linux-gnueabihf, it is not compatible with your gcc (I think it's the tenth time I'm repeating myself).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182884/discussion-between-minding-and-matthieu-brucher).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to install gcc properly using this command:

```
cp -a gcc-*version*/bin/. /usr/bin/
cp -a gcc-*version*/lib/. /usr/lib/
 # ... (for all sub directories)
```

Which just copies all files of the source folder to the destination folder.

Thanks to @Matthieu Brucher for telling me that I installed it wrong and how to install it properly.